# Two-variable generating functions for Laguerre polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, special-functions

Where can I find generating functions for orthogonal polynomials in two variables?
Lebedev's book (Special Functions and their Applications, Dover, 1972) gives a closed form for
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)} L_n^\alpha(x) L_n^\alpha(y) t^n
$$
as an explicit function of $x,y,t$ (it involves a Bessel function). However, I need to sum over the upper index (when it is an integer), to find
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(n+k)!} L_n^k(x) L_n^k(y) t^k = {??}
$$
in a closed form $F(x,y,t)$, for a fixed positive integer $n$. Are generating functions of this kind to be found in the literature? (Not on DLMF, as far as I can see.) A closed form for the previous sum would be great, a pointer to a suitable article would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I think that http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0409066v1 (Multivariate Orthogonal Polynomials (symbolically) page 15, has the representation you are looking for [whether it will help you compute your sum, I am not sure, but maybe their Maple package will do the thinking for you?

Comment: Not really, but its bibliography pointed to an article of Baker and Forrester (Commun. Math. Phys. 188, 1997) that has a nice general theory of multivariate generating functions. Sadly, nothing there about summation on the upper index. 